# Is there a way to play raw 8bit PCM data using pygame?

Tags: python, audio, pygame, game-development, mixer

I'm trying to create an amiga MOD player using Python and Pygame. I've successfully managed to extract the raw sample data from a MOD file but I can't seem to feed it into pygame's mixer. I've changed the frequency and size (-16, 16, -8, 8) but the audio output it just noise.

This is how I'm feeding the data into the pygame's mixer

```
sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer=raw_audio_data)
```

Here's the raw audio encoded using base64 so you can play around with it.

```
RAW_8BIT_AUDIO = b'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'
```

To decode it use:

```
import base64
data = base64.b64decode(RAW_8BIT_AUDIO)
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you.

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of tinkering around I managed to get the audio to play using raw 32bit floating point data and here's how.

```
import structs
import pygame

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, size=32, 4)
pygame.init()

raw = #Raw 8bit PCM data
bit = 1 / 512 # 512 sets the volume, the higher the number the quieter the sample
floats = []
for uByte in raw:
    if uByte > 0x7F:
        n = uByte - 256
    else:
        n = uByte
    floats += [bit * n] * 2 # 2 packs it out a bit otherwise it's too fast
buffer = struct.pack("%sf" % len(floats), *floats)
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer=buffer)
sound.play()
```

EDIT: Found an even simpler way to play it using signed 8bit instead of 32bit floating points

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, size=-8, 4)
pygame.init()

raw = #Raw 8bit PCM signed bytes

buf = b''
for index in range(len(raw)):
    uByte = raw[index:index + 1]
    buf += uByte * 4 # pack that out a bit

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer=buf)
sound.play()
```